# How can I place a label on top of another label?

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to place a label on top of another label? I have a label with a specific background color and I want to place a second label on top of that with a different background color.

Is that possible? I would like smallBar to be on top of bigBar.
I am changing the size of smallBar on various events so I would like it to be on top constantly.

```
public class GuessBarComposite extends Composite{
  public GuessBarComposite(Composite shell, int style){
    super(shell,style);
    bigBar = new Label(this,SWT.NONE);
    smallBar = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

    Color outOfRangeColor= new Color(Display.getDefault(), 139,0,0);
    Color inRangeColor= new Color(Display.getDefault(), 255,140,0);

    bigBar.setBounds(labelOffset,20,barWidth, barHeight);
    bigBar.setBackground(outOfRangeColor);

    smallBar.setBounds(labelOffset,20,barWidth-20, barHeight);
    smallBar.setBackground(inRangeColor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code? Should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StackLayout` to position the `Label`s on top of each other and then you can switch between them by setting `StackLayout#topControl`. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();

    final Composite stack = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    stack.setLayout(stackLayout);

    Label bottom = new Label(stack, SWT.NONE);
    bottom.setText("Bottom");

    Label top = new Label(stack, SWT.NONE);
    top.setText("Top");

    stackLayout.topControl = top;

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Switch");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            stackLayout.topControl = stackLayout.topControl.equals(top) ? bottom : top;
            stack.layout(true, true);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
            shell.getDisplay().sleep();
    }
}
```

---

If you simply want them to appear one after the other (on top in terms of y position), then use a `GridLayout`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Label bottom = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    bottom.setText("Bottom");

    Label top = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    top.setText("Top");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
            shell.getDisplay().sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the grid layout and also used top.moveAbove(bottom)